# How To Get an HTML element from another HTML document and display in current document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm building a web site which lets users post requests on site and others to respond. I have built an app-like form to collect information. In that form I need to display 3 pages.

So I have created one page with the from and and a JavaScript file to handle these 3 pages. Other form-pages are designed separately (HTML only).

I'm planning to load the other two pages into that 1st page with XMLHttpRequest and it works.

But I need to take 3rd page into the 1st form-page (display the 3rd page of form) and change the innerHTML of that 3rd page. I tried it with

```js
function setFinalDetails() {
  document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML = object1.start;
}

//creating a XMLHttpObject and sending a request
//requiredPage is the page we request. 
//elementId is the element we need to display

function requestAPage(requiredPage) {

  selectElementId(requiredPage);
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      m = xhttp.responseXML;
      y = m.getElementById(elementId).innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("hireForm").innerHTML = y;

      //m is a global variable
      //m is the object recieved from XMLHttpRequest.
      //it is used to change the innerHTML of itself(m) and display.

      //y is displaying the 3rd page in the form-page one("id =hireForm")

      return m;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", requiredPage, true);
  xhttp.responseType = "document";
  xhttp.send();
}
```

but that gives an error:

> Cannot set a .innerHTML property of null

find my work on https://github.com/infinitecodem/Taxi-app-form.git

Comment: The variable `elementId` is never declared (so it is null), and you cannot set innerHTML of null, just like the error is telling you

Comment: NB: help yourself by taking the habit to consistently indent your code properly.

Comment: no, elementId is declared, it's a global variable, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: trincot thanks for the advice

Comment: @Laurens  Could you please refer to my GitHub repository?  You would have a full understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It it hard to help you in detail because we do not have a way to reproduce your error and test your code. I can suggest you to use a service like [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) to share your code. I do not know if this service will support to do some xhrRequest on other files in its working tree, you can try.

Your error message seems to reveal that one of your `document.getElementById(...)` is returning null instead of the html elt you want (so the id do not exist in the page).

But again without a way to test, it is hard to help you more sry. I really encourage you to try to share a link to a service (like plunker, etc) that will help others to play with your use case.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, it seems to be so. i think the .innerHTML function in this case running while the request is being processed asynchronously. so is it executing before page loads?